# Grails: Is it possible to prevent a domain class instance from being persisted?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to **create** an (one) **instance** of a Domain class (which, as expected, has a GORM interface to my database) and only use it as a container to pass data around, like a Map object. I want to make *absolutely sure* that my **instance** is *never* going to get persisted in the database. I'm afraid that GORM, with all its cleverness, will somehow manage to save it in the database behind the scene even without an explicit call to `save()`. Is there a way to specify a "do not persist this" clause when **instantiating** my object? I know how to prevent persistence on a domain class, what I want is to prevent persistence on a particular **instance** of the class only.

The solution I have now is to create a class in `groovy/src/` that carries the same properties and methods, and use it as my data container, and do type casts as required. It feels wrong, fails DRY, and hacky.

Of course you may also tell me that I should stop being so paranoid and that Grails is never going to persist an domain class **instance** without an explicit save.

Comment: Use `MyDomain.read()` to load a read only instance of a domain class http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html

Comment: `read()` requires the instance to be persisted already.

Comment: Then what you really want is a Command object and not a domain instance.

Comment: I don't know how to better phrase my question. All the answers and comments have been out of context so far. Please read carefully.

Comment: Just use a Command class that extends your Domain class, it won't be mapped by GORM and you don't have to write any code other than `class MyCommand extends MyDomainClass {}` and be done with it. It will carry over all your constraints and everything. That's what you are looking for. You want a **command object** not a **domain object** they are different for a reason, your need being that reason (among others).

Comment: Thanks Joshua I think you are on to something.

Comment: Defining a Command class as a child of a Domain class does let you use an object that looks and behaves like the Domain class, without the fear of persisting. But still the main question is unanswered – will a new domain instance be saved without explicitly calling save() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails will not save an instance of your domain class without an explicit call to `save()` on the instance. You can create an instance and pass it around, and it will not be persisted.

Comment: This is correct. The only concern with "unwanted saves" is when you retrieve a persisted instance (using `get()` or `find*()`) and change some property values, then `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` persists the changes even **without** a `save()`. But that should not be confused with automatic saving of a new instance – it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 7):

Assume that, you already know how to prevent persistence(table creation) on a domain class. Furthermore, you also know that w/o explicit .save() object won't be persisted.
So, what do you want actually? Is it like.. even if someone accidentally call obj.save(), it will never persist.
Although that doesn't make any sense, but according to your query ,

> Is there a way to specify a "do not persist this" clause when
>   instantiating my object?

Yes, there is a way :

```
class MyFishyDomain {
 String pwd
 // properties 
 // constraints

   def beforeInsert() {
      if (!this.pwd.equals("drago")) return false
    }
    def beforeUpdate () {
      if (!this.pwd.equals("drago")) return false
    }

}
```

Now..

```
new MyFishyDomain(pwd:"drago").save()  // success
new MyFishyDomain(pwd:"rambo").save()  // fail
```

By the way, if you want to permanently disable Create+Update+Delete But at the same time want to issue query against domain then solution is:

```
static mapping = {
   cache usage: "read-only"
}
def beforeInsert() {
   return false
}
```

Comment: Very interesting and clever approach. Thanks for your answer.