# Grails: difference between a plain class and a command object?

Tags: grails

In Grails, one can define a Command object class by calling it *ClassName*Command and use it as a container to pass data around. But what are the difference between that and a plain class defined in `/src/`?

This question stems from [Grails: Is it possible to prevent a domain class instance from being persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908364/grails-is-it-possible-to-prevent-a-domain-class-instance-from-being-persisted) when someone suggested to create a Command object, but it would appear that a plain class inheriting from a Domain class would work just as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no naming convention for command objects, unless you're using a plugin that I'm not aware of.

There are two ways that a class will be considered a command object; the standard one is to use the class as a method argument in a controller action method. All action method arguments are subject to databinding, and for simple types (String, Long, etc.) this is straightforward. If you use a class as an argument, it's considered a command object and an AST transformation extends it to have the `grails.validation.Validateable` annotation, and adds validation methods (e.g. `validate`, `getErrors`, etc.) Typically these classes are defined in the same file as the controller that they're used in, which makes sense if that's the only class that uses it.

Alternately, you can use a `src/groovy` class as a command object - just annotate it yourself. This is a good approach if the class is used by more than one controller.

This is described [in the docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#commandObjects) (just ignore that "A class is only considered to be a command object ..." note).

Comment: Hi Burt. Thank you for answering Grails questions so often. So you're saying that the "Command" appended to the class name isn't actually important, like "Service" or "Controller" is?

Comment: Yes - name rules only apply to (most) artifacts, but these aren't formal artifacts.